# What is the API Key to input for Etherscan Contract Verification in Remix IDE?

Tags: remix

I would like to ask, where can I obtain the said API Key for Etherscan Contract Verification in Remix IDE?

I did provide the API Key as highlighted in Yellow Color but is Invalid API Key.

What type of API Key in Remix IDE need? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: [There you go](https://etherscan.io/register).

Comment: BTW, you can verify the contract also on [Etherscan's designated web-page](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract).

Comment: @goodvibration - many thanks and I shall try.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create Account on https://etherscan.io
2. Go to API section https://etherscan.io/myapikey
3. Create your API Key
4. Add this key to verify smart Contract